# Replace values in one dataframe with another thats not NA

Tags: r

I have two dataframes A and B, that share have the same column names and the same first column (Location)

```
A <- data.frame("Location" = 1:3, "X" = c(21,15, 7), "Y" = c(41,5, 5), "Z" = c(12,103, 88))
B <- data.frame("Location" = 1:3, "X" = c(NA,NA, 14), "Y" = c(50,8, NA), "Z" = c(NA,14, 12))
```

How do i replace the values in dataframe A with the values from B if the value in B is not NA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer in base R:

```
i <- which(!is.na(B),arr.ind = T)
A[i] <- B[i]

A
  Location  X  Y  Z
1        1 21 50 12
2        2 15  8 14
3        3 14  5 12
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
A %>%
     mutate(across(-Location, ~ coalesce(B[[cur_column()]], .)))
```

-output

```
#  Location  X  Y  Z
#1        1 21 50 12
#2        2 15  8 14
#3        3 14  5 12
```

Answer (score 0):

One option with `fcoalesce` from `data.table` pakcage

```
list2DF(Map(data.table::fcoalesce,B,A))
```

gives

```
  Location  X  Y  Z
1        1 21 50 12
2        2 15  8 14
3        3 14  5 12
```